# How to retrieve thumbnail url from Azure table?

Tags: windows, linq, azure, azure-storage

How to retrieve thumbnail url from Azure table using LINQ query?

Comment: Can you post your code on how you upload the thumbnail to Azure? In theory if you use the storage client library from the SDK you can just ask any CloudBlob instance's Uri property for the URL to the blob.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you have a thumbnail already generated you can get access it from the container. Just use DownloadByteArray.

```
var client = this.account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
client.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var container = client.GetContainerReference("containerName");
CloudBlob blob = this.container.GetBlobReference("id");
byte[] bytes = blob.DownloadByteArray();
```

You can also assign a SharedAccessPolicy if you want to secure the uri to the blob. If you want to see more about it you can download the [code for our book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728592.aspx) that has exactly this scenario. We are working on upgrading it to the SDK 1.4 in the next month.